# I want to send the string as the parameter with the Ajax Call how to concatenate the URL string of the ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/GetUserByFirstName/" + $("#data").text(),
    method: "get",
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(result) {
        $("#searchuserbutton").click(function() {
            $("#fetchdata").html(result);
        });
    }
});
```

I want to concatenate the Url of ajax call with a string that i want to search by putting in the ajax call in the action of controller

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to put `$("#data").text()` in the `data` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/GetUserByFirstName/",
    method: "get",
    data: $("#data").text(),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(result) {
        $("#searchuserbutton").click(function() {
             $("#fetchdata").html(result);
        });
    }
});
```

It should create the URL string for you

Comment: thanks Ricardo reyna its oslved